# Silverlight 5 plugin crash or request aborded when using HttpWebRequest

Tags: silverlight, azure, httpwebrequest, azure-storage, silverlight-5.0

I try to upload pictures on azure blob storage and I m having great difficulties to accomplish it.

I'am using the code below to upload :

```
public static void Upload(this Stream payLoad, string uri)
        {
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(uri));
            webRequest.Method = "PUT";
            webRequest.ContentLength = payLoad.Length;

            var state = new HttpWebRequestAsyncState<Stream>() { HttpWebRequest = webRequest, PayLoad = payLoad };

            Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(
                webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, 
                webRequest.EndGetRequestStream, state)
                .ContinueWith(t1 =>
                {
                    var asyncState1 = (HttpWebRequestAsyncState<Stream>)t1.AsyncState;

                    using (var requestStream = t1.Result)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        byte[] buffer = new Byte[4096];
                        while ((bytesRead = asyncState1.PayLoad.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            requestStream.Flush();
                        }
                    }

                    Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(
                        asyncState1.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, 
                        asyncState1.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse,
                       asyncState1)
                       .ContinueWith(t2 =>
                       {
                           var asyncState2 = (HttpWebRequestAsyncState<Stream>)t2.AsyncState;
                           if (asyncState2.PayLoad != null) 
                           {
                               asyncState2.PayLoad.Close();
                           }

                           using (var responce = t2.Result)
                           {
                               if (responce != null) responce.Close();
                           }
                       });
                });
        }
```

When I run this code on my developpement machine (vmware with windows 2008 R2 64bit) I get a plugin crash, when I call that in a loop, with no information that I can use at my level.

When I run this code on my personal box windows 7 ultimate 64bit some files get uploaded some don't and have a status in fiddler : Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server.

The code that call this is:

```
private void FileUploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Multiselect = true, Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg" };

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != true) return;

            foreach (var file in ofd.Files)
            {
                string uri = "http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/" + file.Name + "?sr=c&si=dev&sig=%2FIKx1NhY8FzgYge7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                file.OpenRead().Upload(uri);
            }
        }
```

Does someone see what I m doing wrong?

Thank you by advance

Comment: I get the following error
System.Net.WebException: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult ...

Comment: It seems to occures when files are over 800K, I tried with images 3-5meg and I get the Not Found each time.

May be it's a kind of time out that silverlight report as Not Found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to kaspersky internet security. When disable it, it works.